# Laplacian of bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, graph-laplacian

It is well know that in the case of weighted graph with positive weights, the dimension of the kernel of the Laplacian is the number of connected components of the corresponding graph.

This fails when negative weights are allowed, but I was wondering if this remained true if we restrained ourselves to bipartite graph?

In other words, for bipartite graphs with possibly negative weights, is the number of connected components the dimension of the kernel of the associated Laplacian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I haven't made any error in my code, the answer is **no**

Here is a counter example:

$L=\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 3 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
  0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -1 & -1\\
  -1 & -1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
  0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

This graph is connected, and the Laplacian has eigenvalues $\left({(5 + \sqrt{17})/2, 3, 2, 2, (5 - \sqrt{17})/2, 0}\right)$

Now take the weights:

$L_w=
\begin{bmatrix}
  1. & 0. & 0. & -1. & 0. & 0.\\
  0. & 1. & 0. & 2. & -4. & 1.\\
  0. & 0. & -3. & 0. & 4. & -1.\\
  -1. & 2. & 0. & -1. & 0. & 0.\\
  0. & -4. & 4. & 0. & 0. & 0.\\
  0. & 1. & -1. & 0. & 0. & 0.\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

this has eigenvalues $({-6.82741, 5.88255, -2.55556, 1.50042, 0, 0})$.

for completeness, here is the python code I used to find the counterexample:

```
    import networkx as nx
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline
    #magic
    import warnings
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

    import random

    np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
    import math

    def randomWeightLaplacian(A):
        #given an adjacency matrix, give random symetric weights between -10 and 10 (avoiding 0)
        #return the weighted Laplacian and the Laplacian of the unweighted graph
        n=A.shape[0] #order of the graph
        L=np.zeros((n,n)) #weighted Laplacian
        Lb=np.zeros((n,n),int) #unweighted Laplacian     
        
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(i+1,n):
                if A[i][j]==1:
                    w=random.choice([-1,1])*random.choice([i for i in range(1,10)])
                    L[i][j]=w
                    L[j][i]=w
                    Lb[i][j]=-1
                    Lb[j][i]=-1                

        for i in range(n):         #diagonal
            L[i][i]=-sum(L[i][:])
            Lb[i][i]=-sum(Lb[i][:])        
        return L,Lb


    def numberSmall(array,pres=1e-5):
        #number of small element in the array
        cc=0
        for i in array:
            #print(i)
            if math.isclose(i, 0., abs_tol=pres):
                #print(i)
                cc=cc+1
        return cc


    n,m=3,3       #size of the partition
    ccw,ccb=0,0   #multiplicity of 0 in L and Lb
    i=1
    while ccw==ccb:
        print(i)
        i=i+1
        G=nx.bipartite.random_graph(n,m, 1/3)
        A=nx.to_numpy_array(G)
        #networkx function giving the adjacency matrix of a random bipartite graph
        
        L,Lb=randomWeightLaplacian(A)
        G=nx.from_numpy_array(A)


        eigenval,eigenvect=np.linalg.eig(L)
        eigenvalb,eigenvectb=np.linalg.eig(Lb)

        
        ccw=numberSmall(eigenval)
        ccb=numberSmall(eigenvalb)

    nx.draw(G)

    print("number of connected components:",ccb," mutliplicity of 0 in the weighted graph:",ccw,"\n")
    print(L)
    print(Lb)
```

---

**Edit**

---

my example has a diagonal element $0$ artificially (some weights cancel out) but this is not necessary. One can adapt the code adding/replacing with this piece, and still get counterexamples

```
L,Lb=randomWeightLaplacian(A)
flag=True
for i in range(n+m):
    if L[i][i]==0 and Lb[i][i]!=0:
        flag=False
        
if flag:
    eigenval,eigenvect=np.linalg.eig(L)
    eigenvalb,eigenvectb=np.linalg.eig(Lb)


    ccw=numberSmall(eigenval)
    ccb=numberSmall(eigenvalb)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: Do you know if we can obtain a similar result with regards to connected components in the case of negative weights? Possibly adjusting the definition of the Laplacian, using absolute values of the weights on the diagonal?

Comment: Do you mean only negative weights? If so, yes, because this would be just the regular Laplacian multiplied by -1 or the signless (The least eigenvalue of the signless Laplacian of a connected graph is equal to 0 if and only if the graph is bipartite. In this case 0 is a simple eigenvalue, in Signless Laplacians of finite graphs, D Cvetkovic et al, [I didn't checked the weighted case]). If you mean "take positive and negative weights, then put the sum of the abs values (or the abs values of the sums) for diagonal coefficient", then we still have counter examples with a slight the program